# how to remove user defined objects from java arraylist

Tags: java

how can I remove duplicate objects from below list with using hashset. Can you please help without using equals method

```
public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        customers.add(new Customer(1, "Jack"));
        customers.add(new Customer(2, "James"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));

        //???
    }
}
```

Comment: this link may help you https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/remove-duplicate-elements/

Comment: why without equals? you might end up with huge time complexity

Comment: If you don't define the equals method, how the code is supposed to know if two objects are equal in content.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question :

> how can I remove duplicate objects from below list with using hashset. Can you please help without using equals method

[`HashSet.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) requires the method `equals` to compare elements... so you can't.

> **public boolean add(E e)**
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, **adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))**. If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

Answer (score 0):

you can try my code .... firstly change you Customer class and add two override method

add this code on your **Customer** class

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Customer) {
            Customer temp = (Customer) obj;
            if (this.id.intValue() == temp.id.intValue() && this.name.equals(temp.name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (this.id.hashCode() + this.name.hashCode());
    }
```

and inside your main method

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        customers.add(new Customer(1, "Jack"));
        customers.add(new Customer(2, "James"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));
        customers.add(new Customer(3, "Kelly"));
        //--------------------------------
        Set<Customer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(customers);
        customers = new ArrayList<>();
        customers.addAll(set);
        //--------------------------------
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            System.out.println(customer.getName());
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, My question was wrong. I want to implement with out hashset and equlas method. is there any other way with out hash set.